# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS amd64 freezes during boot from USB 2.0

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I wanted to try out Ubuntu without fully installing it on my PC, so i created a bootable Flash Drive, following these instructions https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 
I have a dell XPS 13 2 in 1. The Flash Drive is USB 2.0, that is put into a USB 3.0 to Thunderbolt 3 Switch. During the restart I hammered the f12 key like a maniac, came to the boot menu of dell and told the pc to boot from my USB 2.0 Flashdrive. I then passed some screens whith wite text on black background, that did not require actions from me and then came to a Screen like this one https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-vs0vHKOfLFA/UIJIBuUQEnI/AAAAAAAABjs/sNxZ9gLwj58/s510/1350715389451.png 
For the first 30 sec, the white dots moved and indicated booting, but then they stopped moving. After 10 min or so i forced my laptop to shut down by pressing the power button. I have tried several times, it is always the same. I only have acess to this PC, so i can't check if the problem is reproducable on other PCs.

Any Ideas what to do?
Thanks in advance,
Padit

Comment: Have you tried with other usb ports? Also would be neat to [check the iso](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu). Be nice with you keyboard :P

Comment: Unable to duplicate the problem. My 19.10 USB boots just fine.

Comment: @guillermochamorro I have two thunderbolt ports, tried it with both. They also work finde for other tasks. I also checked the ISO and completely reinstalled it. Still does not work. But still thanks :)

Comment: @K7AAY I disabled the secure boot, but could not finde options for fast boot it csm or win 10 features in the bios menu. But the disabeling of the secure mode did not help.

Comment: Try with a different version, say 19.10.

Comment: @Padit Here's how to verify the ISO used to make the LiveUSB downloaded correctly: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0

Comment: It gets more bizarre: I tried the ISO on an old laptop of a friend. It worked just fine. so it seams to be a problem with my (Brand new) Laptop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not solve the problem entirely, but found a nice work around! If you create your boot-usb-drive with this http://Pendrivelinux.com instead of rufus and use FAT32 it works fine for me!